# Extracting non-local links - beautiful soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract non-local links (links which are not self referencing or which not belong to the same domain as the webpage I am scraping from) in beautiful soup. e.g. following is the code which allows me to do just opposite:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib import parse, request

def get_links(root, html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    for link in soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile('https://www\.eecs\.mitx\.edu/')):
        href = link.get('href')
        if href:
            text = link.string
            if not text:
                text = ''
                text = re.sub('\s+', ' ', text).strip()
                yield (parse.urljoin(root, link.get('href')), text)

site = 'https://www.eecs.mitx.edu/~professor' #this is an example
r = request.urlopen(site)
for l in get_links(site, r.read()):
print(l)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [custom function](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function) to match your requirements. For example, if you want to scrape this page (current page) and get all links that don't start with `https://stackoverflow.com`, you can use this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_links(root, html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    for link in soup.find_all('a', href=lambda h: h and h.startswith('http') and not h.startswith(root)):
        yield link['href']

r = requests.get('https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49869971/extracting-non-local-links-beautiful-soup')
base = 'https://stackoverflow.com'
for link in get_links(base, r.text):
    print(link)
```

Partial output:

```
https://chat.stackoverflow.com
https://meta.stackoverflow.com
https://stackexchange.com/sites
https://stackoverflow.blog
https://meta.stackoverflow.com
https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/?ref=topbar_help
https://stackexchange.com/users/?tab=inbox
https://stackexchange.com/users/?tab=reputation
https://stackexchange.com
https://plus.google.com/share?
```

You can modify the function `lambda h: h and h.startswith('http') and not h.startswith(root)` as per your needs.

---

Also, in your code, you use `re` module for this line:

```
soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile('https://www\.eecs\.mitx\.edu/'))
```

You can do it without using `re` with the help of [CSS selector](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class) with partial match (`^`). For example:

```
soup.select('a[href^="https://www.eecs.mitx.edu/"]')
```